# ValueError: Dimension must be 4 but is 3 for 'capsule_2/transpose_4' (op: 'Transpose') with input shapes: [?,10,16,16], [3]

Tags: python, machine-learning, text-classification

I am trying to use capsule networks for binary text classification. I use pre-trained fasttext word embedding to vectorize my dataset

, and this is my model definition

```
 gru_len = 128
    Routings = 5
    Num_capsule = 10
    Dim_capsule = 16
    dropout_p = 0.
    rate_drop_dense = 0.3

def get_model(embedding_matrix, sequence_length, dropout_rate, recurrent_units, dense_size):
    input1 = Input(shape=(sequence_length,))
    embed_layer = Embedding(embedding_matrix.shape[0], embedding_matrix.shape[1],
                                weights=[embedding_matrix], trainable=False)(input1)
    embed_layer = SpatialDropout1D(rate_drop_dense)(embed_layer)

    x = Bidirectional(
        GRU(gru_len, activation='relu', dropout=dropout_p, recurrent_dropout=dropout_p, return_sequences=True))(embed_layer)
    capsule = Capsule(num_capsule=Num_capsule, dim_capsule=Dim_capsule,routings=Routings,share_weights=True)(x)
    capsule = Flatten()(capsule)
    capsule = Dropout(dropout_p)(capsule)
    output = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(capsule)
    model = Model(inputs=input1, outputs=output)
    model.compile(
        loss='binary_crossentropy',
        optimizer='adam',
        metrics=['accuracy'])
    model.summary()
    return model
```

**but when the model gets to train, I got an error.
The error log is as below:**

```
ValueError: Dimension must be 4 but is 3 for 'capsule_3/transpose_4' (op: 'Transpose') with input shapes: [?,10,16,16], [3].
```